Add Custom Layout to core fields only to be used in module parameters
For my Joomla5 Module Blueprint Project i would like to show how we can use own layouts for core fields in our modules. The way I see it, this should be easily possible if you create a "layouts" folder within the module and then store the layouts for the individual fields in it. But how do I get Joomla! to use them - what do I have to specify as the field value for "layout=..."?
Even if I try to do the following:
In XML:
...
<fieldset name="content"
                      addfieldprefix="CPM\Module\Modulename\Site\Field"
                      addlayoutprefix="CPM\Module\Modulename\Site\Layout"
...
<field name="title_source_params"
                       type="subform"
                       formsource="modules/mod_modulename/forms/title_source_params.xml"
                       layout="subform.modal"
                />
...

Neither the Layout from mod_modulename/layouts/subform/modal.php nor mod_modulename/src/Layout/subform/modal.php got loaded
Sidenote: Namespacing is correct and placed (even if i think its not necessary?) inside both files:
namespace CPM\Module\Modulename\Site\Layout;
Project on Github where this will be used with adopted namespacing (to know about the structure):
https://github.com/marcorensch/Joomla-Blueprint-Example-Module
When pasting my layouts into the joomla_root/layouts/companyName/... folder they are usable via layout="companyName.form.field.[...]" - but i think that is not the correct / official approach? Also that way i have to move them with my installer script and take care of it when updating / deleting the module aswell...
